# c# null value after deserialize

Tags: c#, json, null

I have a problem with deserialization.

It's my json structure

```
{ "status": "ok", 
  "data": [
    {
      "issued": 1447358848072, 
      "volume": "5.52565454", 
      "currency": "pln", 
      "limit": "724.2500", 
      "type": "bid", 
      "id": "2015/11/12/13328345/4836"
    }, 
    {
      "issued": 1447359927423, 
      "volume": "1.25465440", 
      "currency": "pln", 
      "limit": "1850.5000", 
      "type": "ask", 
      "id": "2015/11/12/13328342/8188"
     }
  ]
}
```

It's my class in C# and functions:

```
public class oferta
{
    public string issued { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string limit { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class tBitCurex_PRV_Offers
{        
    public string status { get; set; }        
    public List<oferta> data { get; set; }
}


public void GetPRV_Offers(tBitCurex_PRV_Offers B)
        {
            try
            {
                var RSP = "my json string";

                B = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tBitCurex_PRV_Offers>(RSP);

                if (B.data.Count > 0)
                {
                    // in here COUNT = 2 and all works fine.
                    // and B.status = "ok"   
                    // but when function is end i have a null
                }
            }

            catch (Exception oException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(oException.Message);
            }
        }

    public void Pobierz_PRV_Offers()
        {
            try
            {
                var BitCurexOfers = new tBitCurex_PRV_Offers();
                GetPRV_Offers(BitCurexOfers);

                if (BitCurexOfers.status == "ok")
                {
                  // do something with BitcurexOffers;
                  // I have a NULL if a use deserialize. 
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                sbInfo2.Text = "Error..xxxx";
            }
            finally
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
```

When in similar fuction i use

```
JObject oObject = JObject.Parse("json string");
B.status = (string)oObject["status"];
```

then all works fine inside and outside the function.

How should i do this properly with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with deserialization but with reference pointers

Instead of void, change the return type of the Function to BitCurex_PRV_Ofers and at the end of the function return B; and assign BitCurexOfers to the result of the function call instead of instantiating a new instance

Or just change the parameter to

```
ref BitCurex_PRV_Ofers B)
```

This is happening because you get a pointer to BitCurexOfers in B, then change that pointer with the result of deserialization

If you use JsonConvert.Poupulate(B); this will also work for you without any other changes

Comment: But i don't I understand why it worked without ref , when i used   'B.status ="ok"'. The result also was not null.

Comment: Which one did you select to go with? There I mentioned three alternative solutions. You say, in a similar function you set B.status = "ok" and it works.That is probably because you are passing B and only set B.status, (accessing the instance that B points to), and not changing the pointer B (like B = JsonConvert.Deserialize(), or like B = new BitCurex_PRV_Ofers();).

Comment: Think of it like this. You pass instance pointer B to a function and B points to say, "Instance A". Now it points to "Instance A" both inside and outside the function. In the function, when you do B.status = "ok", you are doing "Instance A".status = "ok" which is reflected to the outside because both inside and outside pointers point to "Instance A". But if you do B = Json.Deserialize() in the function, then, inside the function now B = "Instance B", while outside, B is still pointing to "Instance A"

Comment: That's why, passing the pointer B as ref works in both cases. If passed in by ref, when you change B (as B = Json.Deserialize), B will point to "Instance B", and you have completely lost the pointer to "Instance A" now because outside the function, B now points to "Instance B" as well.

Comment: The samples and documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) can be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It was exactly what I do not understand. Now I understand the difference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not altering `B` in the caller, just the method in which you're doing the deserialization. You can either change `B` to a `ref` parameter, or you can return it from the method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code has some errors. try adding this attribute and it should work.

[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject(Title = "root")]
public class tBitCurex_PRV_Offers